# Inbox' encoding wrong for apostrophe

Tags: bug, status-completed, comment-replies, global-inbox

In the comments section for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38481292/how-to-get-unique-records-using-linq-when-columns-are-all-varchar?noredirect=1#comment64365356_38481292) Tim Schmelter addressed a comment to me, in which "that's" is rendered correctly:

[image: correct encoding]

However, my inbox is rendering the text incorrect:

[image: faulty encoding]

This is tested on Google Chrome Version 52.0.2743.82 m and IE11

Answer (score 2):

Inbox comments to reply-to users were not getting updated when the source comment was edited.

This has been fixed* and deployed.

<sup>* note that existing inbox items with out-of-sync texts have not been updated.</sup>

Comment: That was a quick fix ... Did someone threaten you with a giant 'strophe?