# Missing character in Inbox preview?

Tags: bug, status-completed, global-inbox

The inbox notification for a new comment is missing a character.

This is the comment in question:
[LINQ conditional where only when prop is not null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40303453/linq-conditional-where-only-when-prop-is-not-null/40303478?noredirect=1#comment67864008_40303478)

Looks like this in my inbox:

[image: Inbox Preview]

As you can see, the "s" at the beginning of "so" is missing

[image: Actual Comment]

Might be related to [this problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328927/inbox-encoding-wrong-for-apostrophe).

Comment: A double quote in a comment is no guarantee that it goes wrong: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2jgX.png

Comment: This one is also bold (**"Test1"** "**Test 2**"), maybe that got something to do with it.

Comment: Excellent test, but no luck: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQHb4.png

Comment: Huh... well maybe he simply edited the comment and the inbox didn't refresh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a pencil icon at the end of the comment, which means that it was edited. I don't think edits to comments show up in the inbox. He posted the comment, it was sent to your inbox with a typo, then it was edited before you hit the page.

Comment: Is there a way to look at the "history" of comments? I think that just might be it.

Comment: @Manfred No, there's not. The pencil is the only indicator of an edit to a comment.